# How to go about doing blob detection on non-circular objects? (No thresholding/binarising)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am working with galaxy images, and I would like to use blob detection to identify the galaxy that is in the center of these images, and then mask the pixels outside of the blobs. I have used cv2 and skimage's blob detection modules, but they only return circular blobs. This would actually be fine as long as the galaxies are fully contained within the circles, but the issue is that the blobs tend to be smaller than the actual size of non-circular blobs (e.g. oblong shaped ones).

Example of blobs being too small:

[image: Example of blobs being too small]

Blob detection results vs actual galaxies:

[image: Blob detection results vs actual galaxies]

I have tried Gaussian blurring.

Are there any implementations/methods for me to be able to get blobs that also match the shape of the galaxy? If possible, I would like to avoid thresholding methods.

My code right now (just a basic use of the packages):

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 5, figsize=(25, 20), sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax = axes.ravel()
i = 0

for galaxy, original_img_data in nsa_galaxy_images.items():
    
    blurred_img = skimage.filters.gaussian(original_img_data, sigma=3)
    blobs_dog = blob_dog(blurred_img, max_sigma=100, threshold=.1, exclude_border=False, overlap=1)
    blobs_dog[:, 2] = blobs_dog[:, 2] * sqrt(2)


    ax[i].set_title(galaxy)
    ax[i].imshow(original_img_data)

    for blob in blobs_dog:
            
        y, x, r = blob
        c = plt.Circle((x, y), r, color='green', linewidth=2, fill=False)

        ax[i].add_patch(c)
        ax[i].set_axis_off()

    i += 1
```

EDIT 1:

As @Cris Luengo suggested, here is code that will allow you to download similar galaxy images to use in python:

```
from astroquery.skyview import SkyView

FAMOUS_GALAXIES_LIST = ['NGC 450', 'NGC 5792', 'NGC 4437', 
                        'NGC 1032', 'NGC 4753',
                        'NGC 60', 'NGC 5496', 'NGC 936',
                        ]

galaxy_images = {}

for galaxy in FAMOUS_GALAXIES_LIST:
    img = SkyView.get_images(galaxy,survey=['SDSSi'], pixels=250,)
    original_img_data = img[0][0].data.copy()
    galaxy_images[galaxy] = original_img_data
```

Comment: Did you try OpenCV SimpleBlobDetector without circularity filtering? However they will still only return circular answers. Maybe you are able to segment your blob better after you use the detector only for finding the presence of the blob, without using the circle for the shape?

Comment: Is your galaxy of interest always in the center of the image?

Comment: Is there a reason why you dont want to threhold the images? Have you considered using [contours](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) instead? You can fit [ellipses](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d62/tutorial_bounding_rotated_ellipses.html) to contours if you are after a bounding area more suited to your images.

Comment: Could you post one or a few of these galaxy images without annotations? It'll allow people to try out a method before proposing it.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you could describe what logic or thinking you apply yourself when manually determining what/where a galaxy is and is bounded by.  That way it might be easier to think how to implement that 'manual' logic.  Also, in your mind, are galaxies irregular shapes, or can they be approximated reasonably by ellipses?  The answer to that would play a big part in the approach.

Comment: An approach might be to a) remove 'background' noise (some different ideas: gaussian blurring, 'remove small objects' (various techniques), or simple thresholding (even though you say you don't want that approach), then b) find peaks (various cv or scikit tools), c) from 'peaks' find 'edges' (contouring, basic image edge growth algorithms etc possible).  I do a lot of image processing for this type of problem, but not astronomy related.  ...usually the solution in this type of problem is to just keep trying many different approaches until you strike on one that works.

Comment: IMO it is a false opinion that these galaxies have a shape at all, as they are smoothly blending to the background. So you need to state a rule to define the outline. As far as I can imagine, the best you can do is to set... a threshold on the density.

Comment: @Micka indeed, all the images i will use have the galaxy at the center of the image.
I think your idea of just using the blob to find the position is a good idea, but i struggle to think of a way to approximate the size of the galaxy in the image to crop the image down to in that case.

Comment: @DrBwts Since the choice of a threshold is rather arbitrary even though the brightness of each star pixel can take on a continuous range of value, it seems rather unscientific for me to use as part of my scientific research (something ive been told too)

Comment: @Cris Luengo thank you! I have edited the post to share code to download the images as I cant attach the source files here

Comment: @Richard The 'overall' shape of all the galaxies can be filled in to be elliptical, so if there was a way to get ellipse blobs i think that would immediately be a solution

Comment: If each galaxy is in the center of the image you dont need a detection at all. Did you try plotting intensities along straight lines through the image center?

Comment: Is the whole galaxy always brighter than the background, even if only a small intensity?

Comment: do you also have source code to save those skyView images to files, after downloading?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution yet, but maybe maybe a good starting point for you.

idea:

1. from the galaxy center (assumed image center): trace intensities until you find the certain background
2. repeat this for different angles

I have used this image

[image]

```
int main()
{
    //cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:/data/StackOverflow/skyView/SAMPLE.png", cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);
    //cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:/data/StackOverflow/skyView/SAMPLE.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::Mat imgColor = cv::imread("C:/data/StackOverflow/skyView/SAMPLE.png");
    std::vector<cv::Mat> colorChannels;
    cv::split(imgColor, colorChannels);
    cv::Mat img = colorChannels[2]; // R channel

    cv::Scalar meanAvg = cv::mean(img);

    

    for (double degrees = 0; degrees <= 180; degrees += 22.5)
    {
        cv::Point2f zero = cv::Point(1, 0);
        double rad = degrees / 180.0 * CV_PI;
        cv::Point2f current = cv::Point2f(cos(rad) * zero.x + -sin(rad) * zero.y, sin(rad * zero.x) + cos(rad) * zero.y);
        //cv::LineIterator lit = cv::LineIterator(img, cv::Point(0, img.rows - 1), cv::Point(img.cols - 1, 0));
        cv::LineIterator lit = cv::LineIterator(img, cv::Point(img.cols/2.0 , img.rows/2.0) - cv::Point(sqrt(2)*img.cols*current), cv::Point(img.cols / 2.0, img.rows / 2.0) + cv::Point(sqrt(2)*img.cols * current));
        int scale = 6;
        cv::Mat plotLine = cv::Mat::zeros(256, lit.count * scale, CV_8UC1);
        cv::Mat plot = cv::Mat::zeros(256, lit.count * scale, CV_8UC1);
        cv::Point prev;
        for (int i = 0; i < lit.count; ++lit, ++i)
        {
            uchar val = *(*lit);
            uchar val_inv = 255 - val;
            cv::Point pos = cv::Point(i * scale + scale / 2, val_inv);
            if (prev == cv::Point()) prev = pos;
            cv::line(plot, prev, pos, cv::Scalar::all(255), 1);
            prev = pos;
        }

        cv::Mat plotFlipped;
        cv::flip(plot, plotFlipped, 1);

        std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
        channels.push_back(plot);
        channels.push_back(plotFlipped);
        cv::line(plotLine, cv::Point(0, 255 - meanAvg[0]), cv::Point(plot.cols, 255 - meanAvg[0]), cv::Scalar::all(255), 1);
        channels.push_back(plotLine);

        cv::Mat merged;
        cv::merge(channels, merged);

        cv::imshow("img", img);
        cv::imshow("plot", plot);
        cv::imshow("merged", merged);
        cv::imwrite("C:/data/StackOverflow/skyView/SAMPLE_plot_" + std::to_string(degrees)+ ".png", merged);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }
}
```

and get this output:

red line is the mean average of the whole image (median would be better)
the other plots are mirrored versions of each other

45° (assumed minimum size

[image]

90° (assumed maximum size)

[image]

all, starting from 0° to 180° in 22.5° steps:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

the sharp zero-peak is the green circle rendered to the image, which wouldnt be in your original image